# C# console application that can find every combination of some numbers but only writes if they can divide by 3

Tags: c#, combinations

I have to perform a task. pls help me. İ want a c sharp console application that can find every combination of some numbers but only writes if they can divide by 3.

We have 15 card in a bag. we will take 3 cards randomly(without replacement) .  After that we will add them(card1+card2+card3) and if their result can divide by 3 then we will write them to console.[(card1+card2+card3)/3]=0

Not sure where to begin with this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Homework assignment?

Comment: Yes. But i am not good at c# i am trying to learn it.

Comment: @dotnetom, "homework" is completely irrelevant.  But it's not a very good question regardless.

Comment: Try writing some code and show us where you get stuck... you must try first a do some due diligence if you want to learn..trust me...ive been there..it would be a good thing to start researching a class with random generator....just sayin'

Comment: Show your card class (or whatever implementation you are using), and specifically where you are stuck. Also, look at the modulus operator instead of division.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given 3 numbers, you can tell if they are divisible by 3 using the modulus operator:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int> {4, 8, 11}; // Represents three random cards

// This will be set to true if the sum of the numbers is evenly divisible by 3
bool numbersAreDivisibleByThree = numbers.Sum() % 3 == 0;
```

Here is an example of how this could be used:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var cardBag = new List<int>();
    var drawnCards = new List<int>();

    // Add 15 numbers to the cardBag
    for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++)
    {
        cardBag.Add(i);
    }

    // Draw 3 cards at random
    var rnd = new Random();

    while (drawnCards.Count < 3)
    {
        var candidateCard = cardBag[rnd.Next(15)];

        // In this implementation, we only add unique cards
        if (!drawnCards.Contains(candidateCard))
            drawnCards.Add(candidateCard);
    }

    // This will be set to true if the sum of the numbers is evenly divisible by 3
    bool numbersAreDivisibleByThree = drawnCards.Sum() % 3 == 0;

    // Output results to console
    Console.WriteLine("The three random cards drawn from the deck are: {0}", 
        string.Join(", ", drawnCards));

    Console.WriteLine("The sum of the cards is: {0}", drawnCards.Sum());

    Console.WriteLine("Is the sum of the cards evenly divisible by three? {0}.", 
        numbersAreDivisibleByThree);
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your help. İt realy helps me but i try to change it for drawn new cards after , shows the result untill there no possible chance for true. The problem is it only drawn the same cards. it always drawn 14, 3, 4.

Comment: @yeter12345 This program above, when run multiple times, picks random cards each time (sometimes a few may be the same, but not all of them). If you are stuck on that, you might consider opening a new, more specific, question.

Answer (score 1):

You can get some idea from this I think.

```
public List<int[]> getCombinations(int[] inArray)
{
        List<int[]> outList = new List<int[]>();
        for (int i = 0; i < inArray.Length; i++)
            for (int j = i + 1; j < inArray.Length; j++)
                for (int k = j + 1; k < inArray.Length; k++)
                        {
                            int[] outCombination = new int[] { inArray[i], inArray[j], inArray[k] };
                            outList.Add(outCombination);
                        }
        return outList;
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
        int[] inArray = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

        // Returned list of combinations...

        Program ns = new Program();

        List<int[]> Combinations = ns.getCombinations(inArray);

        // example: Displaying the results...
        foreach (int[] outArray in Combinations)
        {
            Console.Write(outArray[0] + "," + outArray[1] + "," + outArray[2]);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem like a noob, here is an easy way of looking at it (although not the most efficient and least costly):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace RandomGeneratorPractice
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random random = new Random();

            int randomNumber1 = random.Next(1, 15);
            int randomNumber2 = random.Next(1, 15);
            int randomNumber3 = random.Next(1, 15);

            bool bln = true;

            while(bln)
            {
            if (randomNumber1 == randomNumber2)
            {
                randomNumber2 = random.Next(1, 15);

                bln = true;
            }
            else if (randomNumber2 == randomNumber3 || randomNumber1==randomNumber3)
            {
                randomNumber3 = random.Next(1,15);
                bln = true;
            }
            else if ((randomNumber1 != randomNumber2) && (randomNumber1 != randomNumber3) && (randomNumber2 != randomNumber3))
            {
                bln = false;
            }

            }

            int dividend = randomNumber1 + randomNumber2 + randomNumber3;
            double divisor = 3;
            double quotient = (randomNumber1 + randomNumber2 + randomNumber3) / 3;

            Console.WriteLine("(" + randomNumber1 + "+" + randomNumber2 + "+" + randomNumber3 + ") / 3 = " + (dividend / divisor));

            if (dividend % divisor == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You CAN divide by 3 evenly");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You CANNOT divide by 3 evenly");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to exit...");
            Console.Read();


        }
    }
}
```